# chef: ifconfig resource does not permanently disable interface

Tags: network-programming, chef-infra

I'm trying to have chef disable a network interface in such a way that it will not come up on next reboot.

My resource (in kitchen on debian 7.8) is as such:

```
ifconfig "213.139.12.17" do
  device "eth1"
  onboot "no"
  action :disable
end
```

The interface does go down as expected after converge, but the file at `/etc/network/interfaces` seems to be untouched, and on reboot the interface comes back up since the default settings in the `interfaces` file was "auto".

Why doesn't chef edit `/etc/network/interfaces`? Was it not suppose to? Is there another resource I'm suppose to be using for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hack, but this is what I ended up doing:

```
ifconfig "213.139.12.17" do
  device "eth1"
  onboot "no"
  action :disable
  notifies :run, "execute[remove-auto-eht1]", :immediately
end
execute "remove-auto-eth1" do
  command "sed -i '/^auto eth1/s/^/#/' /etc/network/interfaces"
  action :nothing
end
```

This worked, but I really feel like this should be handled in the `ifconfig` resource when asking it to disable an interface.

Comment: Check out the poise-file cookbook for a more structured approach

Answer (score 0):

I think only the `:add` and `:delete` actions of the ifconfig resource write to configuration files (on some platforms).

So, if you want to keep the interface, but do not want it enabled I guess you can do this:

```
ifconfig "213.139.12.17" do
  device "eth1"
  onboot "no"
  action [:add, :disable]
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. It created a dir `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` and added the conf for the interface to be shut down there but the original file `/etc/network/interfaces` still contained the line `auto eth1` which makes it go up at startup. I'm going to try to add an `execute` resource with a `sed` command that will remove it. I'll update on how it goes. (though I think that the implementation of the `ifconfig` resource should be fixed)

Comment: @TomKlino Ok I had expected the :add action to write the relevant settings (without the auto keyword) to /etc/network/interfaces. Sorry to have pointed you into the wrong direction